# How do I set the default beamer font to Computer Modern serif?

Tags: fonts, beamer, roman

The default `beamer` font seems to be Computer Modern sans serif. How do I change this to serif?

---

*Note:* `\setbeamerfont{<element>}{family=\rm}` seems to work for specific elements such as `title`, but I want this to be a global change.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can put the following in your preamble:

```
\usefonttheme{serif}
```

There are some options to this command. They are described in [§18.1 of the `beamer` manual.](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf#subsection.18.1)