# Sawasdee Font in Beamer Poster

Tags: beamer, luatex, beamerposter

I'm trying to use the "Sawasdee" font in a beamer poster (installed as a TrueType font from fonts-tlwg-sawasdee ubuntu package). I can activate it in a regular (scractl) document by using `\usepackage{fontspec}` and `\setmainfont{Sawasdee}`, and compiling with `lualatex`. However, when I try these commands within the `beamerposter` document class, the font does not change. I looked at this post: [Setting Font attributes in Beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59779/setting-font-attributes-in-beamer), but I could not relate the instructions to using this font, which is a TrueType font separate from LaTeX (correct me if this does not make sense). So how can I force `beamerposter` to use this system font?

Comment: Since Beamer uses the `sffamily` by default, you may need to use `\setsansfont{Sawasdee}` or if you use `\setmainfont` you need to use `\usefonttheme{serif}`.  See [How do I set the default beamer font to Computer Modern serif](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/57383/2693)

Answer (score 3):

Beamer uses `\sffamily` (sans serif) fonts by default, but `\setmainfont` in `fontspec` only sets the `\rmfamily` font.  So there are two ways to solve this problem, you can set the sans font to Sawasdee using

```
\setsansfont{Sawasdee}
```

or you can set the main font to Sawasdee and tell Beamer to use a serifed font theme:

```
\setmainfont{Sawasdee}
\usefonttheme{serif}
```

Since the Latin characters of the Sawasdee font are in fact sans serif, the first solution is to be preferred (and it's one less line of code, too).