# How to get ligatures in beamer?

Tags: beamer, ligatures

While this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}
fi 10\%
\end{document}
```

produces ligatures, this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
fi 10\%
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

does not.

What do I need to do to get the same ligatures in beamer too?

Comment: The sans serif font doesn't have ligatures. If you're asking how to  use the serif font as the default in Beamer, then this question is a duplicate: [How do I set the default beamer font to Computer Modern serif?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/57383)